# Why am getting red line under the Console.ReadLine() method in C# even when storing the user input in string type ?PS. red line removed using var?

Tags: c#, console-application, user-input, console.readline

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter arguments");
string input = Console.ReadLine();// red line under Console.ReadLine
Console.WriteLine("Arguments at run-time  " + input);
```

/*
I want to show the user input in string through my Console.WriteLine method and I know by-default it is in string type so why am getting red line under Console.ReadLine when using string and not when store in var type? Thanks! */

Comment: Are you sure it is a _red_ line?   There is a _Warning_ in your Error List window.

Comment: It is safe to ignore for now, or use `string? input`

Comment: Yeah thanks red line removed using string? or var But am not getting the reason behind the error.. This is the warning in my error-list window of Visual Studio: "CS8600- Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type."

Comment: That's still not an error, and that line isn't red. Read up about "nullable reference types". But as a beginner you may postpone that for a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Console.ReadLine();` function can return a null value and the IDE indicates that for safety. Use `string?`.

Comment: Or disable nullable types in the project settings